# awk:environmental variable substitution in a line after reading from file in another variable

Tags: unix, awk

In Unix i have a file having contents like

```
cat abc
;file1_$HOME;file2_$HOME
```

My shell Script is TRY.ksh having contents:

```
#$HOME is exported and has a value here
echo $HOME 
while read line
do
echo $line
done < abc
```

here `echo $line prints- ;file1_$HOME;file2_$HOME`
but not replaces value of `$HOME`
how this can be achieved?

Comment: The answer of how to do that depends on what you are going to do next. Show us a bit more of your script so we can see how you plan to use that line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `eval` to expand the variables in your file.

Try this:

```
while read line
do
  echo "$line"
done < <(eval echo "\"$(<abc)\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Perl to find the variable names and substitute their value from the environment:

```
perl -pe 's/\$([[:alpha:]_]\w+)/$ENV{$1}/ge' file
```